# SVG <a> tags don't work in Safari

Tags: svg, safari, modal-dialog, webkit, anchor

The `<a>` tags inside my svg link perfectly to my modals in Google Chrome. However, in Safari the links do not work. I thought it was a modal issue, but I tested opening a separate modal and it worked. I think the problem lies in the svg, but I just can't get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

SVG html

```
<object>
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1190px" height="1261px" viewBox="0 0 1190 1261" enable-background="new 0 0 1190 1261" xml:space="preserve">
        <a href="#openRoom4_1">
            <polygon class="roomSVGs" fill="blue" points="626,259 827,324 980,191 775,137   "/>
        </a>
    </svg>
</object>
```

Modal html

```
        <div id="openRoom4_1" class="modalDialog">
            <div class="roomModal">
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">&times;</a>
                <h2>Room 4.1</h2>
                   <p>Hi</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Safari doesn't support href, you'd need to use xlink:href if you want things to work there.

xlink:href is SVG 1.1, href is an SVG 2 feature.

Comment: xlink:href turns my cursor into a hand for a clickable link. It even says "Go to  #openRoom4_1 on this page" in the lower left corner. However, it still does not take me to my modal.